# GLUT: adding menu entries at runtime

Tags: menu, freeglut

I have a scene to which I add and manipulate objects (I'm making a renderer).

I want every camera/object I add to appear on a submenu. I'm using freeglut.

I currently just call the initMenu() function, which creates the menu, every time I add or remove an object, which runs a loop over my database of objects. But it is extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. When you first create your submenu, you are receiving the internal id as return value:

```
int submenu = glutCreateMenu(menu);
```

Later when you want to add another menu item to this submenu, you'll have to set it:

```
glutSetMenu(submenu);
```

And then you can simply add the new value to the menu:

```
glutAddMenuEntry("New submenu entry", 55);
```

While freeglut is not providing a documentation, you can try if it's covered in the [glut documentation](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html). (Although I'm not aware of how much of glut's functionality is covered by freeglut).